# Excel: How to Get a Corresponding Value in Vertical Table Based on Calculated Value in Horizontal Table

Tags: excel, match, vlookup, worksheet-function, data-manipulation

I have a car maintenance schedule arranged in vertical table that has two columns: Mileage and Maintenance Cost at the corresponding Mileage.

Then I have a separate horizontal table that has the car actual mileage traveled at the end of each month (60 columns for 60 months).

I need to find a way in excel to cross-check the actual miles traveled in the horizontal table with the maintenance schedule and get the corresponding maintenance cost whenever the actual miles traveled equals a particular mileage on the maintenance schedule +/-1000 miles.

I tried various combinations of Mod, Match, Index, Vlookup but I couldn't get anything to work. Beside using VBA, is there any way I can achieve that in excel?

Any ideas?

Update:
This is the vertical maintenance schedule:
[image]

And this is the where the corresponding maintenance cost should be selected:

[image]

You can see the same cost values repeating while they should appear only once.

Update: I replaced the screenshots with clearer ones.

Comment: Add a row (Row3?) to your horizontal table that has the mileage rounded to the nearest 1000 miles.  Add another row (row4).  Now `b4 = vlookup(b3, yourVerticalTable,2)`?

Comment: Adam: I'm getting somewhere with your algorithm. I was able to get the cross-checking and getting the corresponding value part right, but now I need to adjust it to never repeat a previously used maintenance cost value. Any ideas? You're great man. Thanks for the brilliant idea.

Comment: _"but now I need to adjust it to never repeat a previously used maintenance cost value."_  I don't know exactly what this means.  Perhaps it means that your vertical table isn't filled out all the way, so when it runs out of values, it repeats the last one over and over?  If so, edit one of your formulas by adding a cursor after the 2. `vlookup(b3, yourVerticalTable,2 **, [CURSORHERE]** )`  With your editing cursor in the formula after the cursor, you should see a tooltip with the words **`[range lookup]`** in bold.  You might need to change this to "0" (exact match)

Comment: Adam: what I meant was that I want it to get the maintenance cost of the 10,000 miles when it the actual traveled miles are at 10,000 miles +/-1000 miles, and never get this value again in the subsequent checks. If this month the car recorded 10,000 miles, and next month it recorded 11,000 miles the algorithm will get the maintenance cost of 10,000 twice. I want it only for the first occurrence. Hope this makes sense. Thanks again.

Comment: Form what you're saying it doesn't look like anything difficult to achieve. Could you post a data sample before and results desired after?

Comment: Note:  In screenshots, it is nice to have row/column headers showing, so that we can refer to particular cells by the same names as each other.  I'll assume that the "maintenance" row is 10, so that the first maintenance value shown (#N/A) is in D10.

Comment: Given my guesses about row/column numbers, then when you calculate a value in F10, you first want to check whether the value in F8 equals the value in E8  (both rounded to the nearest 10,000)  If the rounded values are equal, then the formula should return..._0_?  Otherwise it should perform the vlookup described above?   `=if(mround(F8,10000) = mround(e8,10000),0,vlookup(.....`

Comment: Adam: I used mround() function you suggested to round the actual traveled miles to the nearest 8,000 since the maintenance is done at 8K miles increments. Now the only issue I have is that I need to account for every cost on the maintenance schedule only once, i.e. when it's due. Right now you can see the 8,000 maintenance cost is accounted for twice, once at month 2 and again at month 3. I'm pretty close to get it to work the way we need it to work, thanks to you.

Comment: Yesss I got it to work! In the horizontal table I checked if the rounded miles has been rounded before using match(). If the result is N/A then round, else use 0. For reference, I used this for G11 and it worked IF(ISNA(MATCH(MROUND(G10,8000),$E$11:F11,0)),MROUND(G10,8000),0). Thanks Adam! You've been a life saver. Thanks a million.

Comment: @Adam why not post as an answer, and let it get closed out? It will help for people searching for the question and for people reviewing unanswered questions.

Comment: @user15 I tried previously, but gave up because I didn't know whether to answer with my original understanding of OP's question, or one of the incremental developments that took place in comments.  I have gone back now and answered with the broadest answer that seems like it could reflect an interpretation of the original question, without considering further challenges offered by OP in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

First lets work out how to get a lookup in every column, regardless of whether or not the value in row a is a multiple of 10,000.

Add a row (Row3?) to your horizontal table that has the mileage rounded to the nearest 1000 miles. Add another row (row4). Now *B4* `= vlookup(b3, yourVerticalTable,2)`

You say: *"but now I need to adjust it to never repeat a previously used maintenance cost value."*  Perhaps your vertical table isn't filled out all the way, so when it runs out of values, it repeats the last one over and over?

If so, edit one of your formulas by adding a comma after the "2" in your formula:

`=vlookup(b3, yourVerticalTable,2 , **[CURSORHERE]** )`

With your editing cursor in the formula after the cursor, you should see a tooltip with the words **[range lookup]** in bold. You might need to change this to `0` (exact match)

UPDATE:  With the screenshot, I can refine a little more.  This will restrict reporting to only once per 10,000 miles.

First check whether the value in *F10* equals the value in *E10* (both rounded to the nearest 10,000) If the rounded values are equal, then the formula should return `0` (Or a blank `""`, or whatever else you want) Otherwise it should perform the vlookup described above

`=if(mround(F10,10000) = mround(e10,10000),0,vlookup(.....`